# Azure what's the least amount of memory you can allocate to a container

Tags: azure, memory, containers

For simple containers with tiny memory requirements, what's the least amount of memory Azure will allow to allocate?

Answer (score 0):

The least amount is 100MB (0.1 in the CLI parameter).

As evidence, the following error appears when you try to use less:

> The memory requirement is '0.01' in container 'sftp' of container
>   group 'sftp'. The memory requirement should be in incrememts of 0.1
>   GB.